# Understanding of Fork in C

Tags: c

I have one problem with fork that i don't undertsand.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    main(){
      printf("test 1.\n"); 

      fork();

      printf("test 2.\n");  
    }
```

the output is :

test 1.
test 2.
test 1.
test 2.

Shouldn't i be getting... :
test1
test2
test2

I really don't understand this because fork should create child process after the fork(); and not printing the teste1 again .

Comment: What happens if you add `fflush(stdout);` before `fork();`?

Comment: You're missing the `unistd.h` header.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath +1 the output is `test1\ntest2\ntest2`

Comment: I have ran same code in ubuntu machine and I'm getting same output as you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you , fflush did the trick . if i used write instead of printf this will work too

Comment: your output isn't line buffered? interesting...

Comment: I strongly assume you got these result be piping the program's output into a file. If printing to the terminal you should receive the expected results, as `stdout` by default is line buffered then.

Answer (score 5):

When you call `printf`, it doesn't print any text immediately. Instead it waits until you've printed a lot of text, or you call `fflush(stdout)`, or the program exits. (Edit: There are also other things that will cause buffered text to be printed)

When the process forks, it copies the buffer of un-printed text (which contains "test 1.\n"). Both processes then print "test 1.\n" when they exit.

Calling `fflush(stdout)` before `fork()` fixes this, by making sure "test 1.\n" is actually printed before the process forks.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
void exit_message (void)
{
   // use write to have an unbuffered output
   char m[100];
   sprintf (m, "%d exit\n", getpid());
   write (1, m, strlen(m));
}

main(){
  atexit (exit_message);

  printf("%d test 1\n",getpid()); 

  fork();

  printf("%d test 2\n",getpid());
  }
```

The output will look like this:

```
14866 exit   // <- parent process flushes its output at exit
14866 test 1 // <- parent process: 1st printf
14866 test 2 // <- parent process: 2nd printf
14867 exit   // <- forked process flushes its output at exit
14866 test 1 // <- forked process: unflushed parent process output buffer
14867 test 2 // <- forked process: 2nd printf
```

we can see the only printf done by the forked process is the last one, as expected.

The previous line is a ghost of the stdout output buffer, which has been duplicated by fork() before being flushed.

Making stdout unbuffered

```
main(){
  atexit (exit_message);
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  printf("%d test 1\n",getpid()); 

  fork();

  printf("%d test 2\n",getpid());
}
```

gets rid of the ghost

```
14866 test 1 // <- parent process: 1st printf
14866 test 2 // <- parent process: 2nd printf
14866 exit   // <- parent process exits
14867 test 2 // <- forked process: 2nd printf
14867 exit   // <- forked process exits
```

Comment: The call to `setvbuf()` in the 1st example shall pass `_IOFBF` ("fully buffered") but `_IONBF`.

Comment: @alk AH ok, I see. I had forgotten to remove the line. Post updated, thanks.