# cout vs printf when doing fork()

Tags: c++, fork, printf, cout

I am trying to understand fork() using some test program. And I find different behaviors between cout and printf() :

program 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("Hi , %d\n" , getpid());
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

Hi , 9375

Hi , 9375

program 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hi , " <<getpid() << endl;
    fork();
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

Hi , 7277

The only difference between two program is the first use `printf()` to print the output  while second use `cout`

Can anyone explain it?
Thanks

Comment: `cout = c++` , `printf = c`. You can use at c++ with both of them, but it is always advise to use the native language display functions.

Comment: I only get one output in the first one. Were you writing to a file instead of the terminal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding of Fork in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349944/understanding-of-fork-in-c)

Comment: @OrelEraki My question is when using printf , output "Hi , 9375" is printed out twice while using cout out put "Hi , 7277" is printed only once

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use `stdio`, `stdout` is fully-buffered unless it's writing to a terminal; when writing to a terminal it's line-buffered.

So if you run Program 1 with output redirected to a file or pipe, `printf` writes the line to the output buffer, but doesn't flush the buffer. When the process forks, the buffer is duplicated in both processes. When they exit, they each flush their copy of the buffer, which prints the line.

You would get the same result in Program 2 if you'd written:

```
cout << "Hi , " <<getpid() << "\n";
```

But `endl`, in addition to outputting the newline character, also flushes the buffer. The equivalent in Program 1 would be:

```
printf("Hi , %d\n" , getpid());
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: I think you're right, Barmar, and by constrast, cout << endl always flushes the buffer regardless of whether it's going to a terminal or not.

Comment: std::endl is more than "\n", it is equivalent to call fflush() after printf

Comment: That's what I said. If you changed `endl` to `"\n"` Program 2 would be like Program 1, because it wouldn't flush the buffer.