# Understanding why fork gives different result in C

Tags: c, linux, output, fork

Although there are some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364410/fork-and-output) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349944/understanding-of-fork-in-c)

I still cannot understand why fork gives different output with the following two codes

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    fork();
}
```

Gives output

```
Hello World
```

Where as this code

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    fork();
}
```

Gives output

```
Hello WorldHello World
```

The second case is clear to me from the other questions, that both processes get a copy of the same buffer. So, after the fork, both processes eventually flush the buffer and print the contents to screen separately.

But I am not clear why the  first case is so.

Comment: Tip: What do you suspect would happen if it were flushed already before the call to fork?

Comment: only one hello world

Comment: the difference is the `\n` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723795/is-stdout-line-buffered-unbuffered-or-indeterminate-by-default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain it in simple words:
Consider,these two statements:

> printf("Hello World")

and

> printf("Hello World\n")

The STDOUT is **line buffered** that is **printf** will be executed only when the buffer is **full** or when it is terminated by a **new line** character

> printf("Hello World") will not be guaranteed to display the output unless the
>
> Buffer is **full** or terminated by **new line** character..Thus when a **fork()** is called,
>
> Fork will create a copy of a process,this means that after **fork**, there are two identical processes,
>
> each having a copy of the FILE* **STDOUT** Therefore, each process will have the same buffer contents of **STDOUT**

Since in your second program there is no newline character,

> each process has the string in its buffer.
>
> Then each process prints another string, and all of the contents are printed since it is terminated by a new line character. This is why you see two identical outputs.

But

> In your first program,there is a new line character and it displays output
>
> immediately after the statement is executed and hence it **flushes** the contents of buffer..thus when a fork() is called
>
> The process tries to access the buffer but since the buffer is empty,it does not print anything

Thus,the different response is due to **Buffering** behavior of **stdout**

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 2):

It's due to the buffering behavior.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
void main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    fork();
}
```

flushes the output before you call fork, so the printing is already finished when it was still only a single process.

As to why `printf("Hello World\n");` gets flushed immediately and `printf("Hello World");` doesn't isn't that easy. It depends on the situation. In your case you probably ran it in the commandline where line buffering is common, line buffering means that it will be flushed once you got a newline. If you write to files it might buffer more before you get any output and you might see 2 outputs in the first case too.

If you want consistent behavior with flushing you might want to do it yourself.